# Breaking line inside a set

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

How can I write

```
\[A=\Bigg\{\alpha\in \mathbb{Z}G : \alpha\ \text{is a unit in}\ \mathbb{Z}G\ \text{with}\ \varepsilon(\alpha)=1\ \text{and}\ \alpha+\Delta(G,G')\ \text{has finite multiplicative order in}\  \mathbb{Z}G/\Delta(G,G') \Bigg\}\]
```

So that it looks like

[image]

While I am trying to use `\\` is not working well, and neither multline.

This is what I am asking--

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `align*` which allows to use more lines, if necessary.

Also I would use all the textual sentence inside a single `\text{}` and use `$ $` for math contents inside it.

```
\begin{align*}
A=\bigl\{\alpha\in \mathbb{Z}G :{}& \text{$\alpha$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}G$ with $\varepsilon(\alpha)=1$}\\ 
  & \text{and $\alpha+\Delta(G,G')$ has finite multiplicative order in $\mathbb{Z}G\mathbin{/}\Delta(G,G')$} \bigr\}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{align*}
  A=\bigl\{
        \alpha\in \mathbb{Z}G
   :{}& 
   \text{$\alpha$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}G$ with $\varepsilon(\alpha)=1$}\\ 
   &    \text{and $\alpha+\Delta(G,G')$ has finite multiplicative order}\\
   &    \text{in $\mathbb{Z}G\mathbin{/}\Delta(G,G')$} 
    \bigr\}
\end{align*}
Solution proposed by \texttt{@daleif}.
\[ A=\bigl\{ \alpha\in \mathbb{Z}G :
   \parbox[t]{.7\linewidth}{\raggedright%
   $\alpha$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}G$ with $\varepsilon(\alpha)=1$ and $\alpha+\Delta(G,G')$ has finite multiplicative order in $\mathbb{Z}G\mathbin{/}\Delta(G,G') \bigr\}$.
   }
\]
\lipsum*[2]
\[ A=\left\{\ \parbox[c]{.8\linewidth}{%\raggedright%
   $\alpha\in \mathbb{Z}G : \alpha$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}G$ with $\varepsilon(\alpha)=1$ and $\alpha+\Delta(G,G')$ has finite multiplicative order in $\mathbb{Z}G\mathbin{/}\Delta(G,G') \bigr\}$.
   }\ \right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just use a `\parbox[t]{somewidth}{\raggedright all the math in the world}`? That is what I usually do (combined with a rare exception from the rule of never using ``\\`` inside normal text)

Comment: is there a way to make  these brackets `{, }` to contain all three lines, like we write on paper?

Comment: I want both braces to include whole text, although it is not used in any book, I am just curious. I will try to edit in pic what I am asking for

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth, just use `\left\{ ... \parbox[c]{some width}{\raggedright ....} \right\}`, note how the `\}` is out side the `\parbox`. It does not look nice by default

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth, I edited to include the daleif suggestion.

Comment: @Sigur, that is not my suggestion, only the part after the `:` goes into the `\parbox`

Comment: @daleif, you suggestion is the middle one in the example, isn't?

Comment: @Sigur, two of them, your last example does not have alignment on the `:`, see my comment to Bhaskar above.